# Migradoc Add horizontal line

Tags: c#, migradoc

How can I add a simple horizontal line in Migradoc so as to separate the content above the line from the content below the line?

> Paragraph 1
>
> Paragraph 2
>
> ---
>
> Paragraph 3
>
> ETC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a border to a paragraph or a table.

With respect to your sample, you could add a bottom border to paragraph 2 or add a top border to paragraph 3 or add a new paragraph between them and set either top or bottom border.

Answer (score 11):

from this [repo](https://github.com/benfoster/MigraDoc.Extensions)

```
        var hr = doc.AddStyle("HorizontalRule", "Normal");
        var hrBorder = new Border();
        hrBorder.Width = "1pt";
        hrBorder.Color = Colors.DarkGray;
        hr.ParagraphFormat.Borders.Bottom = hrBorder;
        hr.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 0;
        hr.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 15;
```

Comment: I also had to add a line myParagraph.Format = hr.ParagraphFormat.Clone();

Comment: You should edit your answer to include Hoppe's suggestion as the code snippet you posted doesn't do anything to the paragraph and his code is necessary to make it work.  I would edit it, but any time I edit something it gets reverted anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the game, but here is an example of appending to the existing paragraph format, instead of overwriting as in the answer above, preserving already defined formats:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

p.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
//...any other formats needed
p.Format.Borders.Bottom = new Border() { Width = "1pt", Color = Colors.DarkGray };
```